# Is there any python function to detect the US States from US Circuit?

Tags: python, pandas

the data frame is:

```
US Circuit       #case   
NY,N              202
NY,E              413
NY,S              304
NY,W              106
VT                15
DE                56
NJ                682
PA,E              147
PA,M              132
PA,W              209
VI                0
MD                453
NC,E              84
NC,M              60
NC,W              58
```

I aim to write a python code to detect the US circuits that belong to the same state and return the sum of the cases for that state.

```
US Circuit       #case     state        #total case
NY,N              202        NY            1025
NY,E              413
NY,S              304
NY,W              106
VT                15         VT            15
DE                56         DE            56
NJ                682        NJ            682
PA,E              147        PA            488
PA,M              132
PA,W              209
VI                0          VI            0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need the empty rows you can use groupby transform

```
df[['state', 'code']] = df['US Circuit'].str.split(',', expand=True)
df['total case'] = df.groupby('state')['#case'].transform('sum')
```

```
   US Circuit  #case state  code  total case
0        NY,N    202    NY     N        1025
1        NY,E    413    NY     E        1025
2        NY,S    304    NY     S        1025
3        NY,W    106    NY     W        1025
4          VT     15    VT  None          15
5          DE     56    DE  None          56
6          NJ    682    NJ  None         682
7        PA,E    147    PA     E         488
8        PA,M    132    PA     M         488
9        PA,W    209    PA     W         488
10         VI      0    VI  None           0
11         MD    453    MD  None         453
12       NC,E     84    NC     E         202
13       NC,M     60    NC     M         202
14       NC,W     58    NC     W         202
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the sums, you can split on `","`:

```py
In [4]: df.groupby(df["Circuit"].str.split(",").str[0]).sum().reset_index()
Out[4]:
  Circuit  #case
0      DE     56
1      MD    453
2      NC    202
3      NJ    682
4      NY   1025
5      PA    488
6      VI      0
7      VT     15
```